# I have different output from the same code on Linux VSCode (gcc) and Windows Clion (visual c++)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, visual-c++, clion

I've made a text based game for my project in VSCode (gcc). The main problem is that VSCode gives me strange output while Clion (visual-c++) gives me the right one.

For example in VSCode I get negative numbers as my damage while in Clion I get the right ones.
I hope the code that I provided will help you to find the reason to this strange behaviour

---

I want to know how to fix this problem and how to avoid it in the near future. Thank you in advance

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "mob.h"


using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Random seed
    srand(time(nullptr));

    //Player Initialization



    //Mobs Initialization
    mob Skeleton{rand()%51+50, rand()%21+30, rand()%11, "Skeleton", rand()%11+10};
    mob Zombie{rand()%101+100, rand()%11+10, rand()%21, "Zombie", rand()%11};
    mob Spider{rand()%21+30, rand()%11+20, rand()%11,  "Spider", rand()%21+50};
    mob Creeper{rand()%16+5, rand()%51+50, 0, "Creeper", rand()%6};

    //Array of mobs
    vector <mob> mobs;
    mobs.push_back(Skeleton);
    mobs.push_back(Zombie);
    mobs.push_back(Spider);
    mobs.push_back(Creeper);

    //Fight
    int CurrentAttack = 0, n;

    while (1 < mobs.size())
    {
        //Mobs order output
        cout << endl << mobs[0].name << endl;
        cout << "Choose who to attack:" << endl;
        tryAgain: //In case if user typed wrong number
        for (int q = 1; q < mobs.size(); q++)
        {
            cout << q << " - " << mobs[q].name << endl;
        }
        //Choose who to attack
        cin >> n;
        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                mobs[0].Attack(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[1].TakeHit(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[1].Return();

                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                if (n > mobs.size()-1)
                {   printf("This enemy is already dead");
                    goto tryAgain;
                }
                mobs[0].Attack(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[2].TakeHit(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[2].Return();

                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                if (n > mobs.size()-1)
                {
                    cout << "This enemy is already dead" << endl;
                    goto tryAgain;
                }
                mobs[0].Attack(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[3].TakeHit(CurrentAttack);
                mobs[3].Return();

                break;
            }
            default:
                goto tryAgain;
        }

        if (mobs[n].Health() == 0)
        {
            //Remove dead mob
            rotate(mobs.begin(),mobs.begin()+n+1,mobs.end());
            mobs.pop_back();
        }
        else
        {
            //Rotate Vector for different mob to attack
            rotate(mobs.begin(),mobs.begin()+1,mobs.end());
        }

    }
    cout << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠟⠛⠛⠛⠛⠉⠉⠙⠛⠛⠿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠿⠟" << endl << "⣿⣿⣯⣥⣤⣶⣶⣶⣶⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣷⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣏⣀⣀⣀⡀" << endl << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠿⠛⠛⠻⠿⠟⠉⠉⠉⢻⣿⣿⣿⡿⠟⠋⣡⣼⣿⣿⣿⡄" << endl
    << "⣿⣿⣿⣟⣭⣤⣶⣶⣿⣿⠃⠀⠀⢀⣀⣤⣶⣿⣿⣿⣿⡅⡀⢀⣩⣤⣤⠀" << endl << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣛⡛⠛⠛⠛⢋⣩⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣛⠛⠛⠓⠠" << endl << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣦⣤⣤⣤⣦" << endl
    << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇" << endl << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⢿⡿⢿⣿⣿⣿⠃" << endl << "⠿⠿⠿⠿⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣥⣄⣀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⣾⣿⣿⠏" << endl
    << "⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⣩⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣶⣤⣜⡻⠋" << endl << "⣰⣾⣷⣶⣿⣾⣖⣻⣿⣿⡿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠿⠟⠛⠛⠛⠋⠉⠉⢉⡽⠃" << endl << "⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡉⠉⠉⠛⠛⠛⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡤⠚⠉" << endl
    << "⠛⠛⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠉⠛⢶⣶⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇" << endl << "⠠⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⠟⠃⠀⠀⠀⠈⠲⣴⣦⣤⣤⣤⣶⡾⠁" << endl << "⠄⠈⠉⠻⢿⣿⣿⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠉⠛⠛⠛⠉⠀" << endl;

    cout << endl << mobs[0].name << " has survived!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Mob.h**

```
#ifndef TEXTRPG_MOB_H
#define TEXTRPG_MOB_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class mob {
    int health;
    int damage;
    int armor;
    int attack = 0;
    int agility;

    void Damage(int attack);

    //Types of Attack
    void StrongAttack(int& CurrentAttack);
    void SmallAttack(int& CurrentAttack);
    void Crit(int& CurrentAttack);

public:
    string name;

    void Return();
    void GiveAttack(int& CurrentAttack);
    void Attack(int& CurrentAttack);
    void TakeHit(int attack);
    bool Health();
    mob(int health, int damage, int armor, string name, int agility);

};




#endif
```

**Mob.cpp**

```
#include "mob.h"

using namespace std;

//Attack function
void mob::Attack(int& CurrentAttack) {
    int n;
    cout << "Choose what attack to use:\n1 - Strong Attack;\n2 - Simple Attack;\n3 - Critical Strike;\n";
    cin >> n;
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            StrongAttack(CurrentAttack);
            break;
        case 2:
            SmallAttack(CurrentAttack);
            break;
        case 3:
            Crit(CurrentAttack);
            break;
        default:
            SmallAttack(CurrentAttack);
            break;
    }
}

//Types of Attack
void mob::StrongAttack(int& CurrentAttack)
{
    this -> attack = damage*2;
    mob::GiveAttack(CurrentAttack);
}
void mob::SmallAttack(int& CurrentAttack)
{
    this -> attack = damage;
    mob::GiveAttack(CurrentAttack);
}
void mob::Crit(int& CurrentAttack)
{
    if (rand() % 2)
    {
        this -> attack = damage*3;
        mob::GiveAttack(CurrentAttack);
    };
}

//Share Attack to main.cpp
void mob::GiveAttack(int& CurrentAttack)
{
    CurrentAttack = attack;
}




//TAKE HIT
//Take damage from other mob
void mob::TakeHit(int attack)
{
    if (rand()%101 > agility)
    {
        Damage(attack);
    }
    else
    {
        this -> attack = 0;
        cout << "You missed" << endl;
    }

}

void mob::Damage(int attack) //Health calculation
{
    //Damage Calculation
    if (attack - armor <= 0)
        this -> attack = 0;
    else
        this -> attack -= armor;

    //Health calculation
    if (health - attack <= 0)
    {
        cout << name << " is dead" << endl;
        this -> health = 0;//Health < 0 -> Death
    }
    else
        this -> health -= attack; //Health Calculation
}






//Public

void mob::Return()
{
    cout << name << " took " << attack << " damage" << endl;
    cout << name << " has " << health << " HP left" << endl;
}


bool mob::Health()
{
    if (health == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

//Constructor
mob::mob(int health, int damage, int armor, string name, int agility)
{
    this -> health = health;
    this -> damage = damage;
    this -> armor = armor;
    this -> name = name;
    this -> agility = agility;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some variable is not initialized. Check for any warnings with your code.

Comment: Regardless from the problem - your variable naming convention is horrible. You write `this -> attack` interchangeably to `attack` referring to the class member while in the same scope as `attack` referring to a parameter. Wouldn't be surprised if in`if (health - attack <= 0)` statement you actually meant to refer to the class member `attack` and not the parameter.

Comment: `if (n > mobs.size()-1){ printf("This enemy is already dead"); goto tryAgain;` Also you don't need these blocks, remove them - why to check value of `n` in already matching `case: ` statements!! Besides remove `goto` altogether, it is not recommended, type: `default: continue;` instead - this will go back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: what is this stuff with `int& CurrentAttack`, a function CAN return an `int`